# Retrieve data inside a for loop from firebase realtime database in android java

Tags: java, android, firebase-realtime-database

[image: Current Output]

Iterate through the array and check whether the relevant data exists in the firebase real time database. If data exists set the availability as "Available" and else "Not available". This code isn't setting the availability.

```
    for(int i=0; i<time.length; i++)
    {
        LabTest p1 = new LabTest();
        p1.setDate(date);
        p1.setTime(String.valueOf(time[i]));


        DatabaseReference ref = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference();
        Query query1 = 
        ref.child( "LabSession" ).orderByChild( "Time" ).equalTo( String.valueOf( time[i] ) );

        query1.addValueEventListener( new ValueEventListener() {
            @Override
            public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {


                if(dataSnapshot.exists())
                {
                    setAvailability("Available");
                }
                else if(!dataSnapshot.exists())
                {
                    setAvailability("Not available");
                }
            }

            @Override
            public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError error) {

            }

            private void setAvailability(String ava)
            {
                p1.setAvailability( ava );
            }

        } );

        labTestList.add(p1);
    }
    setUserRecycler(labTestList);
}

private void setUserRecycler(List<LabTest> userList)
{
    userRecycler = findViewById(R.id.time_recycler);
    RecyclerView.LayoutManager layoutManager = 
    new LinearLayoutManager(this, RecyclerView.VERTICAL, false);
    userRecycler.setLayoutManager(layoutManager);
    labTestAdapter = new LabTestAdapter(this, userList);
    userRecycler.setAdapter(labTestAdapter);
}
```

Comment: why are you adding firebase listeners inside a loop ?

Comment: Want to check whether each element in the array has a relevant record in the firebase realtime database.

Comment: Your stuff can't work since the query is asynchronous. You stack as many request as your array size. Then when you get the answer you override your previous setAvailibility with the current one. You need to wait the end of each answer before to process the next one. Or you need to add an Id of what available or not your are setting, or you need to build a better query and process the for inside your unique answer.